# Data Validation based on Condition in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Code | Desc |
| --- | --- |
| 10100 | AA |
| 10200 | AB |
| 10201 | AC |
| 20200 | BA |
| 20100 | BB |
| 20203 | BC |

Hey guys I was wondering if this is possible using only formula in excel.

I have two dropdowns.
The first dropdown contains:
Class A
Class B

And in my second drop down if Class A is selected then the list in 2nd dropdown would be all those with Code where '1' is the first character + their Desc.

and if Class B is selected the 2nd dropdown would list all those with Code where '2' is the first character and the 3rd character is also '2' + their Desc.

For example if I select Class A in my first dropdown the choices on my 2nd dropdown will be:

| 10100  AA            |

| 10200  AB            |

| 10201  AC            |

and if Class B is selected then the choices will be:

| 20200  BA            |

| 20203  BC            |

What I have tried so far is I created a formula to separate the two into Class A and Class B and then use =indirect(). But as the list gets longer the size of the excel file also increased and it is also taking a long time to load. And every time new data is added into the list I also need to change the range that is in reference.

Comment: Which Office/Excel version are you using? With the data shown it is also possible to filter by Desc instead of checking the code - would be easier.

Comment: Use Tables with structured references instead of range references. Then your range references will be dynamic.

Comment: @Ike Excel 2019. The actual data is around line 250k in excel.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tried it, but the main problem is after that I don't know how to make the lists that satisfy the condition appear on my dropdown.

Comment: Do a search for dependent dropdowns. There are a number of suggestions both on this forum and on the internet.